# Oriented Dilation OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

Is there any kind of dilation that we could set like a "pottential field" for the direction of the dilation?

For example, I wold like to fill the black areas inside the squares in the next image.

[image]

so it would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done be a ***flood fill*** algorithm.

[See more here.](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill)